# Trouble with beginning of line anchor in online regex testers

Tags: regex

I seem to be having trouble with the *caret*, the beginning of line anchor, in the online regex testers. For example, here is the screenshot for regexr.com: [image]

I would expect the third line to match as well.

Comment: Why screenshot instead of link?? :S| Btw what regex engine? Tag it. Did you specify multiple line operation?

Comment: @marekful regexr.com does not provide customized links.

Comment: @marekful How do you specify muti-line?

Comment: You can use http://regex101.com it's pretty neat.

Comment: I get the same result as regexr though.

Comment: If you are coding in Ruby, you do not need the `m` flag, `^` and `$` match line start/end by default. And use http://rubular.com

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I doubt that OP codes in Ruby (his tags do not suggest that he does). I also think this is a legitimate question for SO, given the immense convenience provided by the online regex testers to casual regex users across multiple languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are missing a multi-line flag `m` at the end:

[image: Screenshot]

Note the `/gm` at the end. You can add `m` by clicking the small flag icon on the right, and adding a check mark next to "multi line" option. This option means that `^` and `$` *anchors* are matched at the beginning and at the end of each line, as opposed to the overall beginning and the end of the entire input (the default).

Comment: Interesting! Thanks dasblinkenlight and Aydin - this solved the issue. I have been using `egrep` so I was not aware of this - are these flags part of standard regex or just used in these online tools?

Comment: @DDC I think the `m` flag comes for Perl and Javascript. I am not sure, because I'm not an expert in either one of these.

Comment: Looks like the `/gm` is now the default on regex101.com.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable the multiline flag (by checking the relevant box in the editor or adding `/^cat/gm` if you are doing it manually), you will get what you need.
With the current structure, the third line is not treated as a new line.